# Principle curvature and line of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Given a point on a 2 dimensional surface embed in 3D, where exactly does a principle curve differ from a line of curvature? If we look at the definitions, it's not clear to me.

Principle curve: The curve that has $\alpha '(t)$ in the direction of the principle curvature.

Principle curvature: The maximum normal curvature at a given point on a surface.

Line of curvature: Curve that is always tangent to a principle curve

I don't see how that separates it from principle curves. The last definition would mean that $\alpha ' (t)$ is pointing along a principle direction, which would also make it a principle curve. What's the difference?

Comment: Definitions are not quite right here. Princip*al* curvature is a number, an eigenvalue of the shape operator (either maximum *or* minimum normal curvature). A line of curvature is a curve whose tangent vectors are in those optimal directions (i.e., eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues). I've never heard the words *principal curve* before.

Comment: Ok, I see. Principal Curve: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalCurve.html

The textbook used for the course was Do Carmo. I can't recall us ever talking about a shape operator before. It wasn't the best book I've ever used and at times it was quite unclear.